# Details about "Zettai Junpaku Mahou Shoujo"

Tags: zettai-junpaku

I recently saw the OVA for Zettai Junpaku Mahou Shoujo on Youtube but couldn't find out anything else about it.

Is this an existing or preview teaser of some anime? Is there a manga series?

There are some details on myanimelist.net but it's just a review of the OVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you managed to find the myanimelist page you should also have noticed that the review states

> this anime is based of a doujin manga (im pretty sure its a doujin hentai manga but im not 100% percent sure) called mahou shoujo written by Raita its is currently about 10 volumes long and about 25-30 pages per volume. you wont find it on MAL because it was not written and published by a real writer (in other words because its a complete doujin). [source](http://myanimelist.net/anime/16656/Zettai_Junpaku%3a_Mahou_Shoujo/reviews)

It pretty much states that this is a Full doujin written by raita, There is only a ova so far. The chances of it getting a real anime are considerd really low. The ova also did not go through a producer so is most likely home/fan made

If you wish to read the doujin the review provided many links to sources where to read.